# Javascript reporting CORS error when loading google.com

Tags: javascript, cors, fiddler

Here is the snippet of Javascript code:

```
            var requ = "http://google.com";
            var xmlhttp;

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                // BREAKPOINT A
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    // never gets into this block
                }

            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", requ, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
```

Code execution passes through ***BREAKPOINT A*** exactly 2 times.

First time: xmlhttp.readyState == 1; xmlhttp.status == 0;

Second time: xmlhttp.readyState == 4; xmlhttp.status == 0;

Chrome console reports:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50261' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What is the problem? Why can't I get successful response?

**EDIT #1**

So, the problem is that google.com does not support CORS. But maybe I can extend this question in a different direction.

I was using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to send GET on http://google.com.
No Origin header was present in the request. Actually, no headers were specified at all.
Request completed successfully. How can I test if a site supports CORS without writing JS code and executing it? How can I use Fiddler to test the same thing?

**EDIT #2**

I found a [site](http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client) that quickly answers my question.
I would still prefer to know why it doesn't work through Fiddler.

Comment: Read into Same Origin Policy - you are not allowed to make XHRs to different domains. There are a lot of questions about this topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: Fiddler is a local proxy; you can send any requests you want with its Composer; it isn't bound by Same-Origin-Policy since it is not a web app. It will send any header you tell it; if you want to send an `Origin` header, add one.

Answer (score 4):

The readyState indicates the state of your request. readyState essentially equals "connection established" and readyState "request finished".

Your request jumps from 1 to 4 because you get a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) Error. If you were doing a proper request, states 2 and 3 would be included (2: Headers received, 3: receiving response body).

Your Cross Origin Request gets to readyState 4, but actually never holds the 200 status.

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I know about Same Origin Policy. I falsely believed that http://google.com was set up to enable CORS for all Origins. 
Will delete this question...

Comment: I tested the same JS code against another URL of my own for which I was certain that enabled requests from any Origin. It worked as it should, so the question is invalid.